# Shouldn't Captain America's shield still have Black Panther scratch marks on it?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers Endgame*, Capt America dons the infamous vibranium shield again.

Shouldn't his shield, (re)given to him by Tony Stark, have the marks of *Captain America: Civil War* on it?

And to be clear,

> I'm not talking about the end scene with Capt after sending him back to return all the stones.

Comment: Idk, Shuri fixed it?

Comment: Tony made it, presumably Tony can fix it.

Comment: I thought Tony says something to the effect of "I got you a new one"?
But I have only seen it once so far.

Comment: @Paulie_D Tony's father Howard made it, and when he returned it to Cap, he said: "Why not he made it for you". Presumably Tony learned how to work with Vibranium from the Wakandans and fixed the shield himself.

Answer (score 3):

This one can be the new prototype mention in *Spider-Man: Homecoming*:

> Happy: All right, wheels up in eight minutes. We just got to load Tony’s old Hulkbuster armor, prototype for Cap’s new shield, and the Meging... the Meg... the... Thor’s magic belt.  - [transcripts](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_Homecoming)

Also this one look pretty fresh and new not like an old one.

Even similar prototype mentioned before in Iron Man 2:

[image]

Source : [comicbook.com](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/08/24/avengers-4-captain-america-shield-iron-man-spider-man-homecoming/)

Comment: But in Endgame Tony specifically says 'He made it for you' which implies it is the original one that his father made for Steve.